# Update hierarchical / tree structure in Clojure

Tags: clojure, tree

I have an Atom, like x:

```
(def x (atom {:name "A" 
              :id 1 
              :children [{:name "B"
                          :id 2 
                          :children []} 
                         {:name "C"
                          :id 3 
                          :children [{:name "D" :id 4 :children []}]}]}))
```

and need to update a submap like for example:

```
if :id is 2 , change :name to "Z"
```

resulting in an updated Atom:

```
{:name "A" 
 :id 1 
 :children [{:name "Z"
             :id 2
             :children []} 
            {:name "C"
             :id 3 
             :children [{:name "D" :id 4 :children []}]}]}
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with [postwalk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk/postwalk) or [prewalk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk/prewalk) from the [clojure.walk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.walk) namespace.

```
(def x (atom {:name "A" 
              :id 1 
              :children [{:name "B"
                          :id 2 
                          :children []} 
                         {:name "C"
                          :id 3 
                          :children [{:name "D" :id 4 :children []}]}]}))
(defn update-name [x]
  (if (and (map? x) (= (:id x) 2))
    (assoc x :name "Z")
    x))

(swap! x (partial clojure.walk/postwalk update-name))
```

Comment: Splited the update into a function returning the new map:

    (defn update-nested-map [search-key search-val add-map nm] 
      "Find a map which contains search-key search-val and merge 
      this map with add-map."
      (postwalk
        (fn [x] 
          (if (and (map? x) (= (search-key x) search-val)) 
            (merge x add-map) 
            x)) nm))

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **Zippers** from the `clojure.zip` namespace

**Find a working example here**: https://gist.github.com/renegr/9493967