# Clojure nested maps path

Tags: dictionary, clojure, tree, hierarchical-data

This is really a followup to question [Update hierarchical / tree structure in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286932/update-hierarchical-tree-structure-in-clojure)

I need to be able to change an Atom containing a map with lists of submaps. I would like to use fx assoc-in to do this, but i'm not sure how best to optain the path to the element i wich to change

My data structure:

```
(def x (atom {:name "A" 
          :id 1 
          :children [{:name "B" 
                      :id 2 
                      :children []} 
                     {:name "C" 
                      :id 3 
                      :children [{:name "D" 
                                  :id 4 
                                  :children []}]}]}))
```

How do i make a function to find the path go a given id, fx give me path to map which contain #(= (:id %) 3):

```
(find-path 3 @x) ; => [0 :children 1]
```

So i can do this to get a new map:

```
(assoc-in @x [(conj (find-path...) :name)] "Jim")
```

Or update the Atom like this:

```
(swap! x assoc-in [(conj (find-path...) :name)] "Bob")
```

Comment: You could use a zipper from [clojure.zip](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.zip).

Comment: I thought it should be easy to make a recursive function returning the path, but i cannot get it to work.

Comment: In my opinion it's a lot easier to reason about and manipulate persistent nested structures using zippers than to try to figure out a  recursive function to handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fundamental issue here is that your update process is now a two steps process: `find-path` and `update-in`. However you are working with atoms so the path returned by `find-path` may be incorrect by the time `update-in` gets to see the value of the atom.

So you should combine them in a single fn so as to not have one `deref` and one `swap!`.

```
(defn update-by-id [x id f & args]
  (apply update-in x (find-path x id) f args))
```

Now you can use a single `swap!`:

```
(swap! x update-by-id 3 assoc :name "Bob")
```

However if you constantly update and access through ids you should also evaluate switching to another (flatter) representation for this piece of data.

Comment: Good point. The data will be often read and seldom updated, but both operations might be to expensive with a deep structure.

Answer (score 3):

Create a zipper with [`zipper`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.zip/zipper), then iterate through each location with [`next`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.zip/next) and once you find the location that holds the node with the `id` you are looking for, start moving [`up`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.zip/up) building the path along the way.

The following is a function I've used to do the last step, which is move up to the root and build the path along the way.

```
(defn path-from-root
  [loc]
  (loop [path []
         loc loc]
    (if-let [parent (zip/up loc)]
      (recur (into [:children (-> loc zip/lefts count)] path)
             parent)
      path)))
```