# Update tree in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a tree (list of lists), I would like to modify a selected node of the tree.

```
[
  [:a1]
  [
    [:b1, b2]
    [:c1, c2]
  ]
]
```

For example, I would like to append `b3` to the node (array) with `b` entries.

```
[
  [:a1]             ; 0
  [                 ; 1
    [:b1, b2, b3]   ; 1, 0
    [:c1, c2]       ; 1, 1
  ]
]
```

Question: how to update a node given list of indices where I can find the target node (`[1, 0]`)? In other languages, with a mutable tree I could simply find the array, and do `target_node.append("b3")`, which is impossible in clojure.

I would like to avoid explicitly using mutable Java objects.

**Related**

- [Update hierarchical / tree structure in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286932/update-hierarchical-tree-structure-in-clojure)

Comment: Remember that when you have immutable structures you simply return a new tree with the new value put in it's place.

Comment: You might want to use maps instead of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update-in` will do what you want:

```
user=> (def t [[:a1] [[:b1 :b2] [:c1 :c2]]])
#'user/t
user=> (update-in t [1 0] conj :b3)
[[:a1] [[:b1 :b2 :b3] [:c1 :c2]]]
```